# Call exported function in exported function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecma

I need call exported function in another one.

Here is my first fucntion which is called:

```
import initialization from './initialization';
export default (a, b) => {
  console.log('called 1.')
  initialization();
};
```

and here is my another exported function in separated file (initialization/index.js) which I want to call in previous function.

```
export default () => {
  function someInnerFunc() {
     //...
  }
  return () => {
    console.log(called 2.);
  };
};
```

In console I have message only "called 1." so I guess second function isn't called. Can you help me to fix it? Thank you.

EDIT:

first function is called in my app.js like that:

```
handlers(foo1, foo2);
```

I am sure that first function is called because I got message in console, problem is with second one.

Comment: It looks like you're never actually calling the first function.

Comment: Which line is supposed to call the first function? How do you import those functions? [mcve] please.

Comment: @djfdev first function is called but in my app js script ... I just doesn't put it here

Comment: @JJJ check my updated question please .. I doesn't put calling first function here because I guess it is irrelevant. Message of first function is in console so it is 100% called

Comment: So if the problem is with the second function why aren't you showing how you're importing it? It's a function that returns a function so you have to call it twice for the console log to appear, but without seeing a complete example it's just guessing.

Comment: I added import above code

Comment: The function you import as `initialization` doesn't output anything. It declares `function someInnerFunc()` then returns another function that you never call.

Comment: @axiac is possible edit my example to call initialization function directly ?

Comment: What is the point of `function someInnerFunc() {
     //...
  }`?! You should just put that in the module scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `initialization` method returns another function.

You will need to execute that function in order to see the second log message.

```
import initialization from './initialization';
export default (a, b) => {
  console.log('called 1.')
  var initResult = initialization();
  initResult();
};
```

Although it is unclear what you are trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want call initialization function like this :/ is possible to edit initialization function to call it as I did in example?

Comment: @DenisStephanov yes. remove the `return () => {` and `};` around the `console.log`.